# Overlay tree on data set with ggcontour

Tags: r, ggplot2, tree

I am tasked with fitting a classification tree model to the observations below. I then have to place the tree on top of the existing data. It was recommended that I used `p + geom_contour(....)` but I've little familiarity with ggplot.

The code I am provided is below.

I can fit a tree model to the data rather easily, but plotting it only yields the decision tree. How may I overlay a tree model on the existing plot using `geom_contour`?

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
dat <- tibble(
    x1 = rnorm(100),
    x2 = rnorm(100)
) %>% mutate(y = as_factor(ifelse(x1^2 + x2^2 > 1.39, "A", "B")))

circlepts <- tibble(theta = seq(0, 2*pi, length = 100)) %>%
    mutate(x = sqrt(1.39) * sin(theta), y = sqrt(1.39) * cos(theta))

p <- ggplot(dat) + geom_point(aes(x1, x2, color = y)) + coord_fixed() +
    geom_polygon(data = circlepts, aes(x, y), color = "blue", fill = NA)
p
```

To fit a tree model to the data, I type

```r
library(tree)
tree_fit <- tree(y~., dat)
```

The overlay would just be a decision tree fit to the data, e.g. something like this (crudely drawn in MS Paint)

[image]

Comment: Can you include an illustration / sketch of your desired output?

Comment: @Z.Lin Updated. Let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: Can you also include the code you would use to fit the decision tree to your data? From the sketch, I'm guessing you want to plot some sort of decision boundary, but I'm not entirely clear on the logic without a better idea of the tree model itself.

Comment: Separately, since you are generating values from a normal distribution, you may wish to include `set.seed(<some value>)` at the start of your code for reproducibility.

Comment: Good suggestions. I've made all the changes you suggested, as well as adding a seed which should lead to some reproducibility on your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `geom_contour` is the way to do this, but you can get the coordinates for the line segments from `tree_fit`'s underlying data frame, & perform some wrangling to progressively restrict each segment to the still "active" area in the plot:

```
tree.df.segment <- tree_fit$frame %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(rowname = as.integer(rowname),
         depth = tree:::tree.depth(rowname),
         split = splits[, 1] %>%
           gsub("<|>", "", .) %>%
           as.numeric()) %>%

  arrange(depth, rowname) %>%
  mutate(leaf.position = case_when(lead(depth) > depth & lead(var) == "<leaf>" ~ "left",
                                   lead(depth) > depth & lead(var) != "<leaf>" ~ "right",
                                   TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  fill(leaf.position, .direction = "up") %>%
  filter(var != "<leaf>") %>%
  select(depth, var, split, leaf.position) %>%

  # define basic segment coordinates
  mutate(x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = -Inf, yend = Inf,
         xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) %>%

  # modify coordinates of segment / active area based on split
  mutate(x    = ifelse(var == "x1", split, x),
         xend = ifelse(var == "x1", split, xend),
         y    = ifelse(var == "x2", split, y),
         yend = ifelse(var == "x2", split, yend),
         xmin = ifelse(var == "x1" & leaf.position ==  "left", split, xmin),
         xmax = ifelse(var == "x1" & leaf.position == "right", split, xmax),
         ymin = ifelse(var == "x2" & leaf.position ==  "left", split, ymin),
         ymax = ifelse(var == "x2" & leaf.position == "right", split, ymax)) %>%
  # shrink active area progressively as depth increases
  mutate(xmin = cummax(xmin), xmax = cummin(xmax),
         ymin = cummax(ymin), ymax = cummin(ymax)) %>%
  # limit segment coordinates to within active area
  mutate(x = pmax(x, xmin), xend = pmin(xend, xmax),
         y = pmax(y, ymin), yend = pmin(yend, ymax))

p + 
  geom_segment(data = tree.df.segment,
               aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend))
```

[image: plot]

---

Additionally (because I think it's bound to be asked after this), we can shade each area corresponding to a terminal leaf as a rectangle, using `geom_rect`. This will require some additional wrangling.

```
tree.df.rect <- tree.df.segment %>%
  mutate(depth = depth + 1) %>%
  select(-c(x, xend, y, yend)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), list(rect = lag)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(xmin_rect, ymin_rect), ~ifelse(is.na(.), -Inf, .)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(xmax_rect, ymax_rect), ~ifelse(is.na(.), Inf, .)) %>%
  mutate(xmin_rect = ifelse(var == "x1" & leaf.position == "right", split, xmin_rect),
         xmax_rect = ifelse(var == "x1" & leaf.position ==  "left", split, xmax_rect),
         ymin_rect = ifelse(var == "x2" & leaf.position == "right", split, ymin_rect),
         ymax_rect = ifelse(var == "x2" & leaf.position ==  "left", split, ymax_rect)) %>%
  # add label for each rect
  full_join(tree_fit$frame %>%
              rownames_to_column() %>%
              mutate(rowname = as.integer(rowname),
                     depth = tree:::tree.depth(rowname),
                     split = splits[, 1] %>%
                       gsub("<|>", "", .) %>%
                       as.numeric()) %>%
              filter(var == "<leaf>") %>%
              select(depth, rowname, yval) %>%
              arrange(depth, rowname))
# since last split is associated with two rectangles, determine which is the last 'active'
# one in order to assign the labels correctly (doesn't matter in this case since the last
# two labels are both 'B', but this should apply more generally)
if(tree.df.rect %>% filter(depth == max(depth)) %>% pull(leaf.position) %>% unique() == "left") {
  tree.df.rect[nrow(tree.df.rect), c("xmin_rect", "xmax_rect", "ymin_rect", "ymax_rect")] <-
    tree.df.rect[nrow(tree.df.rect), c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax")]
} else {
  tree.df.rect[nrow(tree.df.rect)-1, c("xmin_rect", "xmax_rect", "ymin_rect", "ymax_rect")] <-
    tree.df.rect[nrow(tree.df.rect)-1, c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax")]
}
tree.df.rect <- tree.df.rect %>%
  select(depth, yval, xmin_rect, xmax_rect, ymin_rect, ymax_rect)

# combine into one data frame
tree.df <- full_join(
  tree.df.rect %>%
    select(depth, yval, xmin_rect, xmax_rect, ymin_rect, ymax_rect),
  tree.df.segment %>%
    select(depth, x, xend, y, yend)
)

p.shaded <- ggplot(data = tree.df) + 
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x1, x2, color = y)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = circlepts, aes(x, y), color = "blue", fill = NA) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin_rect, xmax = xmax_rect,
                ymin = ymin_rect, ymax = ymax_rect,
                fill = yval),
            alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y, yend = yend)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  labs(color = "", fill = "") +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("A", "B"))

p.shaded
```

[image: shaded plot]

Which can be easily extended further into animated form:

```
library(gganimate)

p.anim <- p.shaded +  
  transition_states(depth) +
  shadow_mark() +
  enter_fade() +
  labs(title = "{closest_state}")

animate(p.anim, nframes = 10, fps = 1)
```

[image: animated plot]

Comment: @z-lin, well done for such a detailed and descriptive answer. Gives enough food for thought. +1 for the same.

Comment: I get the following error when running your code: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: Attempt to query lazy column with non-natural slicing index.

Comment: I was able to run the code in a clean environment with only the packages listed in the question / answer (& loaded in that order). Which code section triggers the error & are you able to narrow it down to a specific part? You may also wish to check if your tidyverse packages are up to date; I found this error message mentioned [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3777), suggesting it might have been due to the matrices, but it works fine in my package versions.